# Ways to change const value in c++

Tags: c++, constants

`const value` is often used in programming. It gives programmer security that the value will not change in future. Unfortunately, this is not fully enforced. As a consequence it sometimes causes subtle bugs that are very hard to decipher. As an example :

```
int a = 1;
const int& b = a; // I promise I will not change
a = 3; // I am a liar, I am now 3
cout << b; // As I will now show 3
```

It is possible to change `const` values in other ways also; some of them are quite complex and require good amount of code which often gets lost in other segment of code and hence causing bug.

Thus would anyone elaborate upon the possible ways to change a `const value`? Don't worry if you don't know all, many wouldn't (including myself). Just tell all of the ways you know - after all you can only give what you have!

Comment: `a = 3` is not a lie because `a` is non-const. `const_cast<int&>(b) = 3;` would be a lie.

Comment: `b` didnt promise that the value wont change. What is enforced is that you cannot change the value by using the `const` reference directly. I think it is an interesting question, but your example is definitely not the best

Comment: but isn't this example bogus as you're making `b` const not `a` if you did `b=3` then it would fail to compile

Comment: btw it would be rather strange if a non-const `int` would not be allowed to change its value, just because you made a `const` reference to it. This is like assuming people are not allowed to grow, just because the height given in their passport does not change. well not the best analogy but close enough ;)

Comment: @tobi303 It was quite good analogy. I know my example is not the best, maybe not even good. The point is that value of `b` **did change**. This made the assumption `b` shall not change invalid. I know I abused a loophole in a bad way. This indeed caused a subtle bug

Comment: What is the purpose of this question actually ? If for discussion, then this is the wrong place

Comment: `b` is not `const`! It's a read-only reference.

Comment: @tuple_cat it does follow the limitation of `const` that you cannot change it using direct reference. Try for example - `b = 0;`

Comment: Yes. That's what read-only means.

Answer (score 9):

```
const int& b = a; // I only promise I will not change the value via b, nothing more.
```

`const` doesn't guarantee the value won't be changed by other references or pointers. Think of the following code:

```
void f(const int& b) { ... }
...
int a = ...;
f(a);
a = ...;
```

The value of `a` won't be changed inside `f()` (by the passed argument), that's all the guarantee.

`const` is just a helper. If you won't change sth, then make it `const`, then compiler will help you to check it. You still could change the original value in other ways like your code showed, it's still your responsibility, finally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, const_cast can be used to remove effect of 'const' keyword (but not always). For example:

```
    int a= 1;
    const int& b = a;
    a = 3;
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
    const_cast<int&>(b) = 4;
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Answer (score 2):

```
 int a=1;
   const int *b=&a;
    a=3;
   cout<<(*b);
   return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you must first use of a `const` `variable` as a `pointer` then use of `const_cast<data-type>()` statement, like bellow :

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{

    const int *i = new int(0);
    int *n = const_cast<int*>(i);

    *n = 10;
    cout << *n << endl << *i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output will be :

```
10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to alter const values without causing undefined behavior.

The compiler doesn't try to figure out the difference for you between const and non-const values.  It relies on you, the programmer, to inform it through the type system.  *Names* are const or non-const and the compiler enforces constness on the *name*, not the value.

There are times when it seems that you can modify a const value, such as when that value has a reference to some other value and modifies THAT.  First intuition says these cases should not behave this way, but once you really understand and consider const-correctness you find that it's quite consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
int k = 0;
const int *l = &k;
cout<<*l; // 0
k=1;
cout<<*l; // 1
```

Here I declare only one variable as `constant` i.e. `l`. So the variable `l` can't be changed anymore. And I assign `l` to the address of `k`;

But now I can change the value of `k` anywhere, and that will reflect in `l` because they share the same memory.